# Fullscreen wine apps minimizing in awesome-wm

Tags: wine, awesome-wm

My fullscreen wine app, game for example, minimizing when loosing focus. I switch tag in awesome-wm and when I am back, I should press hotkey to run awful.client.restore(). If this game has 'windowed' mode and it enabled, game not minimizing.

I suspect, this is because wine apps has minimized=true by unknown reason. Awesome cant minimize app, when it has focus. I cant determine class of application to make rule, xprop output is empty. But for notepad.exe I can see class of this wine app.

Not sure I want to make rules for each fullscreen app. Advice me, please, why it happened and what is inside wm?

Comment: I would say: The windows games minimise themselves when they loose the focus.

Comment: If it question, yes. Awesome-wm make them minimized when I change tags.

Comment: No, I think the windows minimise themselves. Not awesome minimises them.